# Identical twins DNA numbers (centiMorgans/cMs)

Tags: autosomal-dna

Are identical twins DNA numbers (centiMorgans/cMs) less from grandparents because they are identical twins?

Comment: In DNA, identical twins just look like one person. If my daughter took a DNA test, all of the DNA companies and sites would identify her relationship to my sister as parent/child, with 100% confidence in their assertion. The way Ancestry words it: "the percentage of the time people sharing 3,487 cM have the following relationships: 100% parent child".

Answer (score 1):

You get 1/2 of your DNA from each of your parents. However you do not necessarily get 1/4 of your DNA from each grandparent. You can get more DNA from one grandparent than another. Each of the identical twins would get the same amount of DNA from the same grandparent. But just like the rest of us they might get more from one grandparent and less from another.